# Binary search tree implementation in Python

Tags: python, tree

I am reading about algorithms and got to the binary search trees. I wanted to ask if the following implementation of a Binary Tree is correct.

```
import random

class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Node()

    def insert(self,data):

        self.root.insert(data)

    def delete(self,data):

        self.root.delete(data)

    def print_elements(self):

        return self.root.print_element()

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self,data = None, parent = None):

        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self,data):

        if self.data == None:

            self.data = data
        else:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left == None:
                    self.left = Node(data,self)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            else:
                if data > self.data:
                    if self.right == None:
                        self.right = Node(data,self)
                    else:
                        self.right.insert(data)

    def delete(self,data):

        if self.data == data:

            if self.right == None and self.left == None:        

                if self.parent.left.data == data:

                    self.parent.left = None
                else:

                    self.parent.right = None
            elif self.right == None or self.left == None:

                if self.right == None:

                    self.data , self.left = self.left.data , self.left.left

                else:

                    self.data, self.right = self.right.data , self.right.right

            else:

                counter = self.right
                while True:
                    if counter.right == None:
                        break
                    else:
                        counter = counter.left
                self.data = counter.data
                counter.delete(counter.data)

        else:
            if data < self.data:
                self.left.delete(data)
            else:
                self.right.delete(data)


    def search(self,data):

        if self.data == data:
            return self.data
        else:
            if data < self.data:
                return self.left.search(data)
            else:
                return self.right.search(data)

    def print_element(self):

        if self.parent:

            print self.data, 'is below %s' % (self.parent.data)
        else:
            print self.data

        if self.right != None:
            self.right.print_element()
        if self.left != None:
            self.left.print_element()
```

The other thing I want to ask is, when I am implementing these data structures (also happened with linked lists) I find it easier to implement the methods in the Node class and not in the BT/LL class. Is this normal with Python ? I mean, I see the guides with C++ and the methods are mostly implemented in the BT/LL classes , but they use pointers and pointers are not available in Python. Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Is it on purpose that your implementation can not hold more than one identical value? I mean, `t = Tree(); t.insert(1); t.insert(1)` result in `t` containing only one node. Why?

Comment: Yep, I am not sure how I should handle the same value more than once and this is why I did not include it in the implementation

Comment: (`I wanted to ask …` not holding my breath 'til you do…) Tag python-2x.

Answer (score 1):

`[is below] implementation of a Binary Tree [correct?]`
Without a specification of how a *Binary (Search) Tree* is to behave, that is difficult to tell, Asian style.
Try

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Tree()
    t.insert(0)
    t.delete(1)
    t.delete(0)
```

: While it may be possible to hand-wave *failure to delete something not in the tree*,
not being able to *delete what's in a single-item tree* is *not correct*.